# Simple Proof as part of Merkle-Hellman

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm implementing a [Merkle-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle-Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem) cryptosystem and I have a question about a small detail.

In order for it to work, all potential subsets of the super-increasing sequence must have distinct sums.  That is very easy to prove because the set is super-increasing.

However, I assume it to be true that these sums times r modulo q (where q is larger than any of the sums and r and q are relatively prime) are also distinct, but I can't prove it.

Basically, this is what I need proven:

```
Given two integers x and y.  
For any q larger than x and y, choose r such that gcd(r, q) = 1.
Prove that: x * r ≢ y * r (mod q)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\gcd(r,q)=1$, then $$xr \not\equiv yr \pmod q$$ occurs if and only if $$x \not\equiv y \pmod q.$$

*Proof*:  If $x \equiv y \pmod q$, then $xr \equiv yr \pmod q$.  Now assume $x \not\equiv y \pmod q$.  Since $\gcd(r,q)=1$, we know $r$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ (i.e., $r$ is a unit); its inverse can be found using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).  Hence, if $xr \equiv yr \pmod q$ then $x \equiv xrr^{-1} \equiv yrr^{-1} \equiv y \pmod q,$ giving a contradiction.

This means you need to ensure that $x \not\equiv y \pmod q$.